# Docker multiple containers cgroup resource CPU MEM limitation

Tags: docker, cgroups

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 and would like to restrict the system resources (CPU, MEM) for a subset of my docker containers - not for a particular container. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out some solution. There is a docker param to us on a container start.

**First** you need to create mygroup.slice in `/etc/systemd/system/mygroup.slice` and run `systemctl daemon-reload`.

```
[Unit]
Description=my cgroup for Docker
Before=slices.target

[Slice]
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryHigh=7G
MemoryMax=7.5G
CPUAccounting=true
CPUQuota=50%
```

**After** that one can start a set of containers with the next argument.

```
--cgroup-parent=mygroup.slice
```

And **finally** run `systemd-cgtop` to check the resource allocation.